# How to scroll a "JSON from Viewmodel" array to change the date format for KnockoutJS?

Tags: json, knockout.js

i'm building an MVC3 site and using Knockout / JSON for the first 
time, i'm new to JSON and not so good at Javascript as i would. 
I'm using an MVC3 model in a razor view, parsed to Json

The model in the cshtml is

```
@model IEnumerable<MySite.Models.UserViewModel>
```

Then:

```
var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); 
var viewModel = { 
                fields: ko.observableArray(initialData),
```

etc.....

All works well with foreach bindings in the  of a table showing the 
data etc.. but the problem is that in the JSON array/model there are 
some Date that i need to change to show them correctly.

Actually the dates are displayed like  /**Date(1319929111857)/**

I would scroll all the array and intercept the label "BirthDate" and 
parse the date calling a function like this:

```
function formatJSONDate(jsonDate){ 
    var newDate = dateFormat(jsonDate, "mm/dd/yyyy"); 
    return newDate;
```

How can i do this? 
i tried for hours to use a function like that below but i do not know 
how to call the *BirthDate:* label of the JSON array and change the 
content:

```
formatDate: function() { 
         for (var i=0; i<this.fields().length;i++) 
        {//foreach JSON array item,find BirthDate: /Date(sssf) and encode it correctly}
```

Changing the JSON will show a correct data in the view.

After that i need to be able to edit the fields with JqueryUI Datepicker and resend all the array to the controller and save i to the DB.
I'm doing it well or there are other better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the properties in your ViewModel are DateTimes which is causing the formatting that you are seeing.  Do they need to be DateTimes?

I would make the properties of the ViewModel strings and do the formatting on the server.  Doing the processing on the client is an unnecessary step.

Comment: Thanks. So you suggest to convert the data to string in the controller before passing it to the model? 
I would use the Jquery datepicker, i remember it requires a DateTime object, if not it's ok, but if it need an object i need again to convert it in the client to show the date correctly..

Comment: @user1146891 - Even using Jquery datepicker that shouldn't be a problem.  It has helper functions to both parse and format dates in the format that you desire.

$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, settings ) - Format a date into a string value with a specified format.
$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, settings ) - Extract a date from a string value with a specified format.

Comment: @dmeel Perfect, i converted the data serverside before creating the JSON, now it works as expected on the view. Thanks for your time